# How to jump in j2me game?

Tags: java-me

i am new to j2me and i creating snowboarding game for my device.
  so, how can i implement jump functionality on Fire key press?

Any help??

thanks..

Comment: That's incredibly vague. Could you provide some code and some background?

Answer (score 2):

Use the SnowboardGame API

```
SnowBoarder bob = new SnowBoarder("Bob");

SnowboardGame snowboardGame = new SnowboardGame();
snowboardGame.setCharacter(bob);

snowboardGame.startRace();

bob.jump(FIRE_KEY);
```

Comment: Come on, don't vote down sarkasm.

Comment: @user It's a bit ridiculous that you got three upvotes for a non-answer

Comment: Fledge the ledge, what a belter